# How to calculate the hardware resources needed for webrtc per stream

Tags: video, resources, streaming, webrtc, hardware

I want to know exactly how much processor power, ram memory, gpu etc. is needed for one single stream with audio and video (maybe take the quality of the video and the audio in that calculation too), and hopefully, I'll need a formula to calculate the same thing for n-numbers of streams.

I'm building an app where I'll be sharing real time video and audio to n-numbers of clients (1-to-many) and I'm not sure how much resources should I have. 
Also, I'm not sure exactly what type of hardware should I use, for instance, type of processor, type of router etc. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would be very hard to get exact numbers for something like this, as there are simply too many factors to consider and too many elements that could change during the lifetime of any deployment.

For example, different platforms will have different mixes of software and hardware elements in the video and audio pipelines.

Similarly, the base capabilities of the platform may change over time, or when new patches or updates are released - some of these may speed some things up and some may slow some things down.

The usual way to achieve what I think you are aiming for is to either build a test instance and run it under load, measuring and extrapolating the results, or else build a model in a simulation tool or even just a spreadsheet and use this to estimate the load.